# How to add 25 minutes in datetime format

Tags: python, python-datetime

I need 25 minute add in datetime format. Anyone know how to do this?

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
startingDate = datetime.strptime(startingDate, '%d-%m-%Y %I:%M %p').strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:00+00")
```

If datetime = 2019-07-01 11:00:00+00 then I need 2019-07-01 11:25:00+00

Comment: `+ timedelta(minutes=25)`?

Comment: @jonrsharpe not working

Comment: What exactly do you mean *"not working"*? Give a [mcve]. Bear in mind that you currently end with a *string*, you need to manipulate the `datetime` *before* formatting it.

Comment: @i tried add this method but then i have not seen error but value are not saved in database.

Comment: startingDate = (datetime.strptime(startingDate, '%d-%m-%Y %I:%M %p')+ timedelta(minutes=25)).strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:00+00")

did you try something like this?

Comment: So *give an example of that*.

Comment: @jonrsharpe check parth modi answer. then you will understand how to answer. thanks

Comment: zeeshan @jonrsharpe gave exactly the same answer as Parth did, he said add a time delta of 25 minutes

Comment: @ChrisDoyle ok . thank you every one. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use Datetime's [timedelta](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta).

Example:

```
>>> from dateutil.parser import parse
>>> datetime = '2019-07-01 11:00:00+00'
>>> d = parse(datetime)
>>> d
datetime.datetime(2019, 7, 1, 11, 0, tzinfo=tzutc())
>>> from datetime import timedelta
>>> d = d + timedelta(minutes=25)
>>> d
datetime.datetime(2019, 7, 1, 11, 25, tzinfo=tzutc())
```